# Options for running django with apache, mod_wsgi, windows

Tags: python, django, windows, apache, mod-wsgi

I have a working django project, build with:

```
python 2.7  
windows  
apache 2.2  
mod_wsgi
```

I've used to download apache binary from:  https://www.apachelounge.com/download/

Unfortunately, apache lounge has stopped building binaries with VC9 (since mid jan, according to the forum), which is the version of VS that python 2.7 is compiled with.
As I've said my current setup is with apache 2.2, VC9 binary, downloaded from apache lounge. But I don't have this `.msi` anymore (probably deleted it, as I usually do with .msi files after I install them).
 So I can't setup apache+mod_wsgi with django in another windows server.

What are my options?  I'm willing to upgrade to apache 2.4, but there is no binary built with VC9, and according to this page:
https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/tree/develop/win32
mod_wsgi binary must match to the VS version used to compile python and apache.

Suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can run django as a stand-alone process and then use `mod_proxy` to redirect requests to it from apache, while letting apache serve the static files itself. My wsgi server of choice is gunicorn, but it's not available on windows. While frowned upon, it is also possible to use the django built-in server in production as long as the static resources are not handled by it as described earlier. I've got a site running using this method right now, and it works just fine.

Reverse proxies communicate with the backend server via sockets, so VC mismatch is not an issue. [Here's a tutorial for setting it up](http://www.apachetutor.org/admin/reverseproxies).

Of course, ideally, you should move away from windows servers if you're not using IIS or other windows-specific technology.

Comment: Are you saying that it would be prefered to run django on IIS if I run in windows? Cause im not sure regard using the dev server for production.